# GWT: Running the development mode code server (from Eclipse)

Tags: gwt

i am only start learning GWT by following their tutorial on https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.1/tutorial/create

On that page, when i reach the heading **Running the development mode code server (from Eclipse)**, i copied the generated url **http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997** to my browser.

It eventually times out, says page not loading...the plugin page did not show up initially, so i manually installed the plugin...but it still times out...

On the screen, it says...

===============================================================================

### The connection was reset

```
 The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
 If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
 If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web
```

==============================================================================

Am i missing any configurations etc?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: it's off topic, but is there a reason you are using the docs for GWT 2.1 ?

Comment: @DoItNow: do you have a local firewall that could be blocking the connection?

Comment: @Jean-Michel Garcia, no, there is no particular reason...didnt pay much attention to the version...thought it shouldnt make much difference..

Comment: @Thomas Broyer, i did turn off the anti-virus software...but it didnt work...

Comment: Dumb question, but when the server is running, did you tried to ping the two ports ? 8888 and 9997

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia, when i run netstat -na, it only shows    

127.0.0.1:9997         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

it does not show


127.0.0.1:8888         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

But the copied url is http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: Which browser are you using ? did you tried others ?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia, i tried it on chrome and Firefox10

Comment: Did you tried to ping as I said ? I'm not talking about netstat

Answer (score 1):

It still looks like your browser is missing the GWT developer plugin. Try a different browser (preferably Chrome). You can also check the instalation of GWT in Eclipse. Look into Windows/Preferences and under Google/WebToolkit you should see checked GWT SDK. Also you can check if a jetty server runs on port 8888, when you type "`netstat -na`" on the command line.

Comment: I don't think that's the case (missing plugin). AIUI, the browser doesn't even reach the Jetty server to load the HTML host page (so it hasn't yet seen the code to load the plugin)

Comment: It looks your system is missing some prerequisites. What is the output when you type `java -version` to a command line? You shoud see something like `java version "1.6.0_26"`. If not you should install java and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.